# Symfony 2.1 Errors when sending email in prod Mode

Tags: symfony, swiftmailer

When in prod mode emails don't send through swiftmailer.  Everything works as expected when in dev mode. Here is what I get to the log file:

*Edit: Edited file path and domain for privacy, added line returns for easier reading.  Made sure SO formatting matched file format.*

*UPDATE: I've chmod -R 777 the app/cache and app/log directory. Everything still works as expected using dev, but now in prod, no error is logged to apache or app/log.  The email is still not being sent.*

```
[Sat Mar 14 20:57:03.896889 2015] [:error] [pid 31767] [client 216.99.32.6:54233] 
PHP Fatal error: 
    Uncaught exception 'Swift_TransportException' with message 'Connection could not be established with host localhost [Connection refused #111]' in /my_project_path/vendor/swiftmailer/swiftmailer/lib/classes/Swift/Transport/StreamBuffer.php:259 
Stack trace:
    #0 /my_project_path/vendor/swiftmailer/swiftmailer/lib/classes/Swift/Transport/StreamBuffer.php(64): Swift_Transport_StreamBuffer->_establishSocketConnection()
    #1 /my_project_path/vendor/swiftmailer/swiftmailer/lib/classes/Swift/Transport/AbstractSmtpTransport.php(115):Swift_Transport_StreamBuffer->initialize(Array)
    #2 /my_project_path/vendor/swiftmailer/swiftmailer/lib/classes/Swift/MemorySpool.php(74): Swift_Transport_AbstractSmtpTransport->start()
    #3 /my_project_path/vendor/symfony/swiftmailer-bundle/Symfony/Bundle/SwiftmailerBundle/EventListener/EmailSenderListener.php(52): Swift_MemorySpool->flushQueue(Object(Swift_Transport_EsmtpTransport))
    #4 [internal function]: Symfony\ in /my_project_path/vendor/swiftmailer/swiftmailer/lib/classes/Swift/Transport/StreamBuffer.php on line 259, referer: https://example.com/admin/requests/view/277
```

I am using sendmail (which is working in dev mode and outside of symfony).

I'm at a lost as for what to try next, Can you suggest where to go from here?

**app/config/config.yml**

```
...
# Swiftmailer Configuration
swiftmailer:
    transport: %mailer_transport%
    host:      %mailer_host%
    username:  %mailer_user%
    password:  %mailer_password%
    port:      %mailer_port%
    spool:     { type: memory }
...
```

**app/config/parameters.yml**

```
parameters:
    ...

    mailer_transport:  mail
    mailer_host:       localhost
    mailer_user:       ~
    mailer_password:   ~
    mailer_port:       ~

    ...
```

Note: Changing mailer_transport to 'sendmail' produces the same result.  I doubt there is an issue here as this file should be consistent between dev and prod.

**app/config/config_prod.yml**

```
    imports:
- { resource: config.yml }

#doctrine:
#    orm:
#        metadata_cache_driver: apc
#        result_cache_driver: apc
#        query_cache_driver: apc

monolog:
handlers:
  main:
      type:         fingers_crossed
      action_level: error
      handler:      nested
  nested:
      type:  stream
      path:  %kernel.logs_dir%/%kernel.environment%.log
      level: debug
```

**app/config/config_dev.yml**

```
imports:
    - { resource: config.yml }

framework:
    router:   { resource: "%kernel.root_dir%/config/routing_dev.yml" }
    profiler: { only_exceptions: false }

web_profiler:
    toolbar: false
    intercept_redirects: false

monolog:
    handlers:
    main:
        type:  stream
        path:  %kernel.logs_dir%/%kernel.environment%.log
        level: debug
    firephp:
        type:  firephp
        level: info

assetic:
    use_controller: true

#swiftmailer:
#    delivery_address: me@example.com
```

**web/app.php**

```
use Symfony\Component\ClassLoader\ApcClassLoader;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

$loader = require_once __DIR__.'/../app/bootstrap.php.cache';

// Use APC for autoloading to improve performance
// Change 'sf2' by the prefix you want in order to prevent key conflict with another application
/*
$loader = new ApcClassLoader('sf2', $loader);
$loader->register(true);
*/

require_once __DIR__.'/../app/AppKernel.php';
//require_once __DIR__.'/../app/AppCache.php';

$kernel = new AppKernel('prod', false);
$kernel->loadClassCache();
//$kernel = new AppCache($kernel);
$request = Request::createFromGlobals();
$request->trustProxyData();
$response = $kernel->handle($request);
$response->send();
$kernel->terminate($request, $response);
```

**web/app_dev.php**

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

$loader = require_once __DIR__.'/../app/bootstrap.php.cache';
require_once __DIR__.'/../app/AppKernel.php';

$kernel = new AppKernel('dev', true);
$kernel->loadClassCache();
$request = Request::createFromGlobals();
$request->trustProxyData();
$response = $kernel->handle($request);
$response->send();
$kernel->terminate($request, $response);
```

Other info of possible relevance:

- Site is behind a proxy (dosarrest in this case)
- "symfony/swiftmailer-bundle": "2.1.*"

Comment: so, just for clarification, you're saying that on the exact same machine, everything works if the environment is dev, but not if the environment is prod?  Is this correct?

Comment: Show your config.yml for swiftmailer setting.  There is something wrong with your configuration as there is `Swift_Transport_EsmtpTransport` in backtrace which `mailer_transport:  mail` should not use. You still having smtp transport somehow

Comment: DerickF - correct same machine, everything works, no log messages,  Email is received on external mail servers when set to dev.  The only thing I change is the .htaccess from app.php to app_dev.php (which is why I posted them).

@SeriousDron updated my config.yml.  Can you set smtp transport outside of config?

Comment: Do you really have no indents in your config.yml or it's just SO formatting issues?

Comment: It was just SO formating as I pulled the info using cat from the command line. (Updated all the above by pulling from my text editor).